# Can't get a deployment job output variable to pass to another deployment job

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to use Azure DevOps to configure a docker swarm cluster, with an environment containing 3 RHEL7 vm's with Docker installed and one of them being configured as the swarm host.

Here is the yaml file for the pipeline:

```
jobs:
- deployment: MasterNode
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - bash: |
            SWARMTOKEN=$(docker swarm join-token manager -q)
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tokenswarm;isOutput=true]$SWARMTOKEN"
          name: setvar
        - script: echo $(setvar.tokenswarm)
          name: echovar
  environment:
    name: swarm
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: SwarmNodeMaster

- deployment: SwarmNode
  dependsOn: MasterNode
  variables:
    tokenvar: $[ dependencies.MasterNode.outputs['deploy.setvar.tokenswarm'] ]
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - bash: |
            echo $(tokenvar)
  environment: 
    name: swarm
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: SwarmNode
```

I have logged this over at VSD https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/937451/unable-to-share-variable-from-one-deployment-job-t.html

I have tried setting the second deployment job to a normal job as per the syntax at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-164-update#support-for-output-variables-in-a-deployment-job

```
jobs:
- deployment: masternode
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: | 
            SWARMTOKEN="Docker GUID"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token;isOutput=true]$SWARMTOKEN"
          name: 'setvar'
        - script: echo $(setvar.token)
          name: echovar
  environment:
    name: swarm
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: SwarmNodeMaster

- job: 'swarmnode'
  dependsOn: 'masternode'
  variables:
    tokenvar: $[ dependencies.masternode.outputs['deploy.setvar.token'] ]
  steps:
  - script: echo $(tokenvar)
    name: echovar
```

It seems whatever I try I can't get the variable to expand in the next deployment step.

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:
@Kontekst thanks for sharing your working yaml, using that i've managed to track it down to defining the environment for the "master" node:

```
environment:
      name: swarm
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: SwarmNodeMaster
```

The swarm master node has the tag "SwarmNodeMaster" and is part of the same environment as the 2 other VMs which have the tag "SwarmNode" which is used in the second step if I change the above to just environment: 'swarm' I can pass a variable to the next step, but again stops working if I try and target the master node...

Here is the yaml that successfully passes a variable to the next deployment job: 
https://hastebin.com/gudelokufi.bash

My main problem is that I need to get the token from the swarm host to the swarm nodes, but when I try and pass a variable from the deployment step that targets the swarm host, to the deployment job that targets the swarm nodes, the variable cannot be expanded in the second deployment job...

This is what I want to work, but seems to break the output variable: https://hastebin.com/yocepowopu.bash

Comment: Try this and let know if it works ---- tokenvar: $[ dependencies.masternode.outputs['masternode.setvar.token'] ]

Comment: @Kontekst No that didn't work

Comment: I cannot find any problem right now. You can take a look at my previous yaml where I have been testing this functionality. It works for me now. You can check differencies between yours and mine yaml, it may help a little. Job B logs in console "My IP variable = SomeIpAddress" so seems this yaml is wornking correctly.

https://hastebin.com/heruqaveze

Comment: Please describe answer for future users, my yaml code will expire in 30 days :P

Comment: I've updated the OP, I still can't get what I want to work..maybe what i'm trying to do is unachievable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after much trial and error I found that when you use environment tags as part of a deployment job, it appends the job name with the environment resource name, followed by the lifecycle hook. This is the working code:

```
stages:
- stage: MyStage
  jobs:
  - deployment: masterNode
    displayName: AnyDeploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment:
      name: swarm
      resourceType: virtualmachine
      tags: swarmnodemaster
    strategy:
      runOnce:
       deploy:
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: 'Setting output variable'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              token=Some_Value
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token;isOutput=true]$token"
              echo $token
          name: setvarStep
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'env | sort'

  - deployment: swarmNode
    dependsOn: masterNode
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment:
      name: swarm
      resourceType: virtualmachine
      tags: swarmnode
    variables:
      myToken: $[ dependencies.masterNode.outputs['masterNode_<resource name>_Deploy.setvarStep.token'] ]
    strategy:
      runOnce:
       deploy:
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: 'Checking if output variable was passed'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo My docker token = $(myToken)
```

I haven't found a way to reference the job name as a variable yet, as the value changes with each job, but the system variable is "SYSTEM_JOBNAME"